# Python class error AttributeError

Tags: python

I have a class like

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = RoboBrowser(history=True,\
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0)'\
        Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1,parser='lxml'

    def test(self,text):
        self.browser.open('https://www.url.com/'+urlthread)
        return self.browser.find(class_='postfoot').find(class_='ip').get('title')[5::]
```

but if I call:

```
In [0]: mc=myclass()
In [1]: mc.test('textblabla')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

So, to debug, I tried in console:

```
In [0]: mc=myclass()
In [1]: brw=mc.browser
In [2]: brw.open('http://www.url.com/textblabla')
In [3]: brw.find(class_='postfoot').find(class_='ip').get('title')[5::]
Out[3]: 'WORKS FINE'
```

I can't understand why it actually works in console and not with the class...

Can you help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: You should include the library you are using as a part of your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, have you tried debugging the code? For more info on debugging, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Is there a difference in `'http://exemple.com/textblabla'` and `'http://exemple.com/test'` for `.open()` method?

Comment: You need to provide more detail in order for people to actually answer. You need to show more of the code. With what's currently shown, it is impossible to answer. We don't know where "wedontcare" gets assigned because that isn't shown.

Comment: I tried to make a more readable code since I use Robobrowser/request. If I copy past something, that will be quickly a huge post for nothing.
I will add some stuff on the post

Comment: You gotta show the part  which is throwing exception. We care about `functionmybrowser(...).weddontcare`.

Comment: Post edited with more details. If you need anything else, feel free to ask. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
RoboBrowser(history=True,\
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0)'\
        Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1,parser='lxml'
```

`\` is used for multi line string concatenation. There are errors in `RoboBrowser()` initialization.

It should be in this format:

```
RoboBrowser(session=None, parser=None, user_agent=None,
                 history=True, timeout=None, allow_redirects=True, cache=False,
                 cache_patterns=None, max_age=None, max_count=None, tries=None,
                 multiplier=None)
```